# Cross compiler standard libraries

Tags: c++, c, linux, cross-compiling

I've been trying to build a cross compiler for the Sega Megadrive system so that I can test out a C game that I have been working on. I've been following the steps in [this](http://gendev.spritesmind.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=889) tutorial however I have run into an issue.

As part of the tutorial there is an example project which I have tried to compile using the cross compiler but I encounter a compiler error telling em that the stdlib.h cannot be found.

After some research I found that I must compile the standard libraries using my cross compiler to successfully compile programs using the compiler however I have not been able to find any instructions to do this.

Does anyone here know how I would go about compiling these standard libraries in order to compiler the project? I should that the tutorial is for Linux systems and that I am running Ubuntu 14.04 (amd64).

Kind regards,

Sam

Comment: You have to port a C library. This is a non-trivial task.

Comment: Isn't `newlib` a standard library you're looking for? It ought to have `stdlib.h` etc. I think you should check where newlib headers and libs are and adjust your project accordingly

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux It is far more complex than that. Sample the [README](https://sourceware.org/newlib/).

Comment: Googling "megadrive toolchain" turns up this:  https://github.com/noname22/megadrive-gcc.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland Thank you for the link but I wanted to do it myself to learn how to build cross compilers in the future.

Comment: Sure, it is more complex. But step 4 of gendev tutorial is to download (and presumably) build `newlib`. There should be `stdlib.h` in your installation, I just cloned whole `newlib` repository from cygwin and stdlib.h is present

Comment: Checkout http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/ You'll find walk-throughs for building several cross-compilers and this may give you a hint

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux I followed the whole tutoprial inclduing the newlib part, however I am still getting this error do I need to copy files from somewhere in order to get this to work?

Comment: How about pointing to right place using either compiler switches or envirnment variables?